# Land cover classification algorithms in SEPAL

Tags: sepal

What is the algorithm for land cover classification employed by [SEPAL](https://sepal.io) in the  `Classification recipe` ?
I am not able to find any options to view the algorithm being used so I don't know if it's possible to choose between different ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default classifier used in SEPAL is a [random forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) classifier with 25 trees.

It is not yet possible to select custom one